# Convert a PCL to a regular Class Library

Tags: .net, dll, portable-class-library

I currently have a `Portable Class Library` whose code is entirely compatible with a regular `Class Library` without any modification.

I was wondering if there was an existing software to do the conversion automatically ; I looked into the Visual Studio tools but could not find any suitable. Before writing my own I just wanted to be sure!

Comment: If the code is entirely compatible, why do you want to convert it? Just use the PCL as-is in your own project.

Comment: I use an old version of Xamarin which does not support PCL.

Comment: Is "recompile it for a different target" an option? Or are you trying to work at the dll level? If so: is it signed/strong-named?

Answer (score 56, accepted):

The differences will be in your .proj file.

Having tried it myself you will have to do *all* of the following;

1. Remove the `<TargetFrameworkProfile>` element
2. Remove the `<ProjectTypeGuids>` element
3. Change where you have #2 (below) for what I shown in #1

**1. Regular class library**

```
<Import Project="$(MSBuildToolsPath)\Microsoft.CSharp.targets" />
```

**2. Portable class library**

```
<Import Project="$(MSBuildExtensionsPath32)\Microsoft\Portable\$(TargetFrameworkVersion)\Microsoft.Portable.CSharp.targets" />
```

Comment: You also need to remove all references to non pcl dll like System etc.

Comment: I think that should be you need to *add* references to things like System and System.Core when going from PCL to normal. (which is what it sounds like the OP was asking) After the changes listed here, I had no references to anything, but it was easy enough to add them back. Thanks!

Comment: Worked nicely. Thanks a lot.

Comment: Also need to set correct `targetFramework` in `packages.config` and restore packages.

Answer (score 6):

Use VSCommands, it has as a build in functionality to convert Projects to PCL. Right mouse click on Project and convert.
It´s free and part of Visual Studio extensions
http://vscommands.squaredinfinity.com/Features-SolutionExplorer

Update 2016-10-12:
Above link is dead. The tool has been rewritten for Visual Studio 2015 and can be found here: https://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/c84be782-b1f1-4f6b-85bb-945ebc852aa1

Comment: That's the opposite of what the author wanted to do. They already have a PCL and want to convert it to a regular class library.  Also, the link is now broken.