# How do I convert a Portable Class Library to a regular Class Library?

Tags: visual-studio, portable-class-library

Is there an automated way within Visual Studio to convert a project of type **Portable Class Library** to a regular (platform-specific) **Class Library**?

I need to reference a library which doesn't happen to be portable.

Answer (score 0):

You have to edit your PCL's .proj file.

I'm not aware of anything within visual studio itself but the steps are easy enough to do yourself.

See my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20094075/convert-a-pcl-to-a-regular-class-library/23135170#23135170)