# Missing targets in VS 2013

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-2013

I'm working with compiling the google apps API and I haven't seen it where I'm missing.

[image: Properties of project]

.net and windows 8/8.1 are both listed but nothing else.  I'm running VS 2013 on a Windows 7 computer.

Because of this, when I go into references to the project, I'm missing all of the original microsoft references (even if I go to add them, there's nothing to select from).

For example, the error I'm getting is: Warning  2   The primary reference "System.IO", which is a framework assembly, could not be resolved in the currently targeted framework. ".NETPortable,Version=v4.0,Profile=Profile5". To resolve this problem, either remove the reference "System.IO" or retarget your application to a framework version which contains "System.IO". Google.Apis.Admin.Directory.directory_v1

I'm not sure why that and all the other microsoft API's are not showing up when I go to select them (or not allowing me to compile).  I assume it's because of the .netportable and the fact I'm not on a Windows 8.x computer.

Anyone know how to change the target?  I don't see anyway of doing that.

Comment: What does the "Change" button bring up when clicked?

Comment: Windows 8 / 8.1, silver light, windows phone, and .net 4 / 4.5 (no Windows 7)

Comment: Are the Google APIs only built for Windows 8?

Comment: No, they're not.  I was using the nuget's version before this.  (I have to sign them and I can't do ildasm because of the referenced objects within the project itself so I need to compile and sign).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you have there is a [Portable Class Library](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/gg597391%28v=vs.100%29.aspx). It's lacking many namespaces and functions that are native to Windows only; basically, a PCL is reduced to the minimum feature set of .NET that can run on all target platforms.
For many missing namespaces there are replacement PCLs; if none is available, you can define interfaces in the PCL (and implement them in platform-specific code) that serve as a "bridge" between the PCL and e.g. the System.IO namespace on Win32.

Simple example: You define `IFileIO` with `WriteFile(...)` and `ReadFile(...)` in the PCL; then every project that uses the PCL (ex.: `WindowsIO` Windows) has a class that implements `IFileIO` and executes the System.IO calls within the respective functions.
Then you combine the Windows-specific implementation with the PCL interface; imagine you have a ImageConverter class that reads, modifies and writes images. Its constructor accepts an `IFileIO`, where you can pass a `WindowsIO` instance (or Win8IO, or AndroidIO, or ...). The ImageConverter only uses the interface and doesn't care about the implementation.

Comment: That's what i was thinking; thanks for the confirmation.  Anyway I can change the target?  I just need a temporary fix until they release a signed version of the API

Comment: @DaBlue: You could try [converting it to a regular class library](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20094075/convert-a-pcl-to-a-regular-class-library). I don't know what subset of .NET the Windows 8 target has, but I guess most namespaces should be covered.