# How to convert a Portable Class Library (PCL) to a normal class library?

Tags: .net, visual-studio, visual-studio-2013, .net-4.5, silverlight-5.0

I have a Portable Class Library (PCL) that needs conversion to a normal class library (targeted only at .NET 4.5).

I've tried editing the `.csproj` file, with no success. I'm wondering how to do this?

Comment: "I've tried editing the .csproj file, with no success", you must show what you tried, and what was the result of what you tired. Include in your question the before and after of the section of the .csproj file you edited and explain how it was not behaving the way you wanted after the change.

Comment: @Scott Chamberlain I've clarified the question. I suspect that the only way  to do this is to edit the .csproj file.

Answer (score 10):

Got it! I reversed the instructions here:

http://geekswithblogs.net/imilovanovic/archive/2012/08/31/vs2012---how-to-manually-convert-.net-class-library-to.aspx

Delete this from the `.csproj` file:

```
<ProjectTypeGuids>{786C830F-07A1-408B-BD7F-6EE04809D6DB};{FAE04EC0-301F-11D3-BF4B-00C04F79EFBC}</ProjectTypeGuids>
```

And change this ...

```
<Import Project="$(MSBuildExtensionsPath32)\Microsoft\Portable\$(TargetFrameworkVersion)\Microsoft.Portable.CSharp.targets" />
```

... to this:

```
<Import Project="$(MSBuildToolsPath)\Microsoft.CSharp.targets" />
```

### Update

See [Convert a PCL to a regular Class Library](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20094075/convert-a-pcl-to-a-regular-class-library).